# How to declare and use variable in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, variables, hive, hiveql

I am using below syntax to declare and use variable in hive sql query. But it gives me an error as below

```
SET aa='10';

SELECT
col1 as data,
${aa} as myVar from myTable;
```

ERROR:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify aa at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime

I have also tried using hiveconf

```
SELECT ${hiveconf:aa} from myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass variable like that. You need to use `--hivevar`. You can create a hql file with below script - hiveqry.hql. Pls note you can use either a normal variable or with hivevar keyword.

```
select * from ${hivevar:aa};
select * from ${aa};
```

Then call that script like below
`beeline --hivevar table=myTable --hivevar aa=100 -f hiveqry.hql`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Hive version, when you are setting variable without explicitly specifying the namespace (`hiveconf` or `hivevar`), it may work with `hiveconf` as a default namespace or may not work.

BTW this works in Hive 1.2:

```
SET aa='10';
SELECT ${hiveconf:aa};
```

If you specify the namespace explicitly when setting variable, it will work with both hivevar and hiveconf

Works:

```
SET hivevar:aa='10';
SELECT ${hivevar:aa};
```

Also works:

```
SET hiveconf:aa='10';
SELECT ${hiveconf:aa};
```

Does not work:

```
SET aa='10';
SELECT ${hivevar:aa} as myvar;
```

Also if above commands do not work, check if variable substitution is enabled (default is true):

```
set hive.variable.substitute=true;
```

If set to false, substitution does not work.

Read the documentation: [LanguageManual VariableSubstitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am using Zeppelin. And When I test with your suggested query:
     SET hivevar:aa='10';
     SELECT ${hivevar:aa};

Got this ERROR:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not recognize dynamic form with type: hivevar

Comment: @DineshMadhup Read this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4556 It was resolved in version 0.9.0. "This PR allow user to override the form type via paragraph local properties. e.g. %jdbc(form=native) "

Comment: I did try using %jdbc(form=native) but still getting error like: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not recognize dynamic form with type: hiveconf