# How to pass variable values of a hive script, to a shell script within it

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline, hivecli

I have a hive script which takes parameters in the form of --hivevar
var_name="value" from beeline and the substitution works well within hive queries.

Within this hive script, I wanted to run a shell script with a variable passed as a parameter.
I tried

```
!sh /home/tempscript {variable_name}
```

But the script does not take the substituted value, rather it passes the string '{variable-name}' to the shell script.

Any way to get around this?

Comment: coulc you please follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864397/how-to-declare-and-use-variable-in-hive-sql/64871022#64871022

Comment: It should be `${var_name}` - with dollar.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question so that it's more clearer

Comment: @KevinBobby Did you ever find out the fix for this? I am wondering about using !sh in beeline too. It seems that if you use beeline and !sh echo "${var}", it will literally print "echo ${var}".

Comment: The problem is trying to do variable substitution within beeline while accessing shell from there.