# Run Hive Script with variable - problem with passing variable

Tags: variables, hive, parameter-passing, hiveql, dbvisualizer

I'm using DBVisualiser to run the following script (Expecting to pass variable in query and retrieve data based on where condition)

```
set Id='1';

select * from MyTable where account_id = '${hivevar:Id}' limit 5
```

Unfortunatelly, when I run this script I see that query which is executed is as follows:

```
set Id='1';

select * from mytable where account_id = '${hivevar:Id}' limit 5
```

But when I run query with hardcoded value

```
select * from mytable where account_id = '1' limit 5
```

then I get expected dataset.
I would apprecaie if anyone could help me to learn what I do wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In DbVisualizer you need to use another syntax: `select * from mytable where account_id = '${id||1' limit 5;`. Read more in: http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG/Using+DbVisualizer+Variables

Answer (score 0):

Variables which were set without namespace are hiveconf variables, not hivevar. Though you can specify the namespace explicitly.

Try this:

```
set Id=1; --No need to quote here if it is quoted in the select
-- use hiveconf
select * from MyTable where account_id = '${hiveconf:Id}' limit 5;
```

Or this:

```
--specify the namespace
set hivevar:Id=1;
select * from MyTable where account_id = '${hivevar:Id}' limit 5;
```

See also [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871766/2700344).